# TypeORM - where Type 'Survey' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<Survey>'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem with findOne on TypeORM, I need to find a course from courseRepository, where survey = survey found in the search above, but, this happens.

This is the error:

> Type 'Survey' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator | FindOptionsWhere | FindOptionsWhere[] | EqualOperator'.
> Type 'Survey' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere'.
> Types of property 'created' are incompatible.
> Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'never'.

This is my code, I found a survey and pass this on find argument

```html
  async getDocumentsByCourse(id_course: string) {
    const created = await this.surveyRepository.findOne({
      where: { Name: 'TEST DENIS' },
    });
    console.log({ created });
    
    const aux = await this.courseRepository.findOne({
      where: { survey: created },
      relations: ['survey'],
    });
    console.log({ aux });
  }
```

And this are my relations:

```html
  //this is on courseEntity
  
  @ManyToOne(() => Survey, (survey) => survey.course)
  survey: Survey;
  
  //this is on surveyEntity
  
  @OneToMany(() => Course, (course) => course.survey)
  course: Course;
```

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
const aux = await this.courseRepository.findOne({
      where: { 
        survey: { 
           id: created.id // assuming fk is id
        }
      },
      relations: ['survey'],
    });
```

The `relations: ['survey']` is optional unless you want to eager load survey entity into course entity. Not found any examples in the document, but I've tried and being using it with Postgres DB for my projects.